# user custom directive as angularUI popover content

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

What I am trying to archive is to have a popover to show the user detail information when I click on the username. And I would like to use a partial to template the detailed information that will be displayed in the popover, however, I don't really know how to do it and this is my code:

jade:

```
a(ng-click="setUser(node)", popover="{{userInfo}}", popover-placement="bottom") {{node.ownerObj.first_name | capitalize}} {{node.ownerObj.last_name | capitalize}}
```

controller:

```
app.controller('userInfoPopoverCtrl', ['$scope', 
        function($scope) {
            $scope.setUser = function(node) {
                $scope.user = node.ownerObj;
            }
        }

    ])
```

directive:

```
app.directive('userInfo', function() {
        $scope.userInfo = function() {
            return {
                templateUrl: '../partials/userInfo'
            }
        }

    });
```

As you can see, I tried to use the directive 'userInfo' as the popover content, but it does nothing.

Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution myself.. so instead of using angularUI, I switched to angularStrap, which comes with the function that let's me to do what I want. Personally, I think it is a better option over angularUI.